# Retrieve Data in Angular from JSON object

Tags: html, json, angular

How do I retrieve only the first word , in this case "Koobiyo" from angular html?

json object:

```
{
    "otherInformation": "Koombiyo,Kurunegala,Kuliyapitiya"
}
```

I want to access from it here, like this?

HTML:

```
<td>
    {{ issue.otherInformation }}
</td>
```

how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple pipe,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: "sliceWords" })
export class SliceWordsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, start: number, end?: number): string {
    if (value == null) return null;
    return value
      .split(",")
      .splice(start, end)
      .join(" ");
  }
}
```

and use it as,

```
{{issue.otherInformation | sliceWords:0:1}}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z7pvqg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fslice-words.pipe.ts)